# Nodejs app not opening

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I have deployed my **Express nodejs** app on Heroku. The app uses mongo db but I haven't attached the mongolab or anyother service with the app on heroku yet, so the mongodb urls in the source code are still **LocalHost:xxx**.

I deployed the app on heroku and it got deployed successfully. However when I got to the app url, heroku says

[image]

I have checked the logs under Activity tab on heroku and it didn't mention any **crash or error** keyword anywhere.

What can be causing this problem and how can I resolve it?

***Here are the logs:***

https://pastee.org/uqf8e

The app logs say `PendingAppointment.js`not found. It's confusing because the file is in the source code and it was working and performing well on my local machine.

Comment: check `heroku logs` in command line.

Comment: It gives the same logs as shown on the website

Comment: you need to post that, just application error is no meaning.

Comment: ok I am posting the logs here

Comment: do `heroku logs -t` and access the page? so you should see some error from application, not just build log.

Comment: I have shared the app logs. Please have a look

Comment: PendingAppointments is.js in same folder as routes/index.js? may be do `heroku run bash` to login into heroku server and check the file is really there?

Comment: Yes the file is in there.

Comment: may be try to run your application locally with `NODE_ENV=production node app/app.js`, there is chance that your application behave different on production mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be several reasons behind this issue like:

- You are missing a dependency
- Your app is crashing upon running
- Path is not valid for some .js file

I had the same issue. In my case the problem was caused by a .js file name mismatch. I renamed a .js file, changed its name everywhere in the app, however heroku kept giving me module missing error. What I ended up doing for debugging was:

I cloned my heroku project git repo on my machine. The command is:

```
heroku git:clone -a YOUR_APP_NAME
```

looked inside the code and found out that Heroku didn't reflect the renamed .js file in the source code of the files. I renamed the .js file and pushed the code to bitbuket which deployed it to heroku via codeship and voila everything started working.